# issue inserting NULL field in datetime column

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2012, ssms, isnull

I am having an issue with this code below. It give me this error:
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The datevalue is either actually NULL (not text NULL) and the date is in the format 2016-12-02.

Anyone know how to get round this, have tried using cast and convert into datetime, this hasnt worked....

```
select  PersonalID
    ,[LeaveDate] as [LeaveDate]
into 
    #temp1
from (SELECT
         [staffid] as PersonalID
         ,[leaving_d] as [LeaveDate]
     FROM 
         rcmsql4.[SSTRESS].[dbo].[vwGetStaffDetails]
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 
         [StudentId] as PersonalID
         , NULL
     FROM 
         rcmsql4.[SSTRESS].[dbo].[vwGetResearchStudentDetails]) x
GROUP BY
    PersonalID
    ,[LeaveDate]


INSERT INTO [dbo].[STG1StaffProfiles]
           ([PersonalID]
           ,[LeaveDate] --datetime field)
    select * from #temp1
```

Comment: Tidy up your code. (Remove empty lines etc.)

Comment: Looks like [LeaveDate] has invalid text values... can you find out what they are like? For example, empty text: '' or NULL text: 'NULL'...

Comment: So they are the actually value NULL not text NULL

Comment: What about the non-NULL [leaving_d] values returned from [vwGetStaffDetails]? Are they returned as strings, and if so, are they formatted to look nice for people? While fooling around in SSMS I noticed that `select convert(datetime, 'November 24, 2016') as foo` worked fine, but `select convert(datetime, 'Thursday, November 24, 2016') as foo` failed with the error message you cited.

Comment: this is how the date looks 2016-12-02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try casting :

```
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[STG1StaffProfiles]
       ([PersonalID]

       ,[LeaveDate] --datetime field
      )
SELECT [PersonalID],CAST(COALESCE([LeaveDate],'01-01-1999') as DATE)
FROM #temp1
```

Comment: I want to keep the NULL, NULLs not replace with 1999

Comment: Then leave the `COALESCE()` , try without it. @LaurenBuxton

Comment: still the same issue Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.